# Difference between ip link eth down and ip link dev eth down

Tags: ip, linux-networking, ifconfig

What's the difference between `ip link set eth0 down` and `ip link set dev eth0 down` ?

The difference between the commands does not appear to be documented anywhere.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

There's no difference; `dev` is optional provided the device name can't be mistaken for another keyword that the `ip` command understands. For instance, if you had an interface named `bridge` then you would have to use `dev` as `bridge` is also a keyword that `ip` uses.

This is undocumented behavior, but it certainly appears to work.

You'll know if you ran afoul of `ip`'s option parser if you get a (slightly grammatically incorrect) message like:

```
either "dev" is duplicate, or "bridge" is a garbage.
```

For things that absolutely must be 100% working all the time, like network configuration scripts, you should include `dev` just to be sure.

Comment: as much as i love ip cmd over ifconfig/netstat/route/etc, i always wondered why it is so leniant with syntax.... (i wish "ip" would exist on freebsd)